# YAML exception: Invalid Yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, encryption, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to implement encryption a Tomcat Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have just followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-java.html), and created a `.ebextensions/https-instance.config` file.

[image]

But when I deploy to the server, I get:

> The configuration file .ebextensions/https-instance.config in
>     application version thewhozoo-1.0.0.25 contains invalid YAML or JSON.
>     YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning a simple key in
>     "", line 4, column 1: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ^ could not
>     found expected ':' in "", line 5, column 1:
>     MIIDnDCCAoACCQCzIxYAYJicIjANBgkq ... ^ , JSON exception: Invalid JSON:
>     Unexpected character (f) at position 0.. Update the configuration
>     file.

What I am doing incorrectly?

**UPDATE**

I changed the file to:

[image]

But get the following:

> The configuration file .ebextensions/https-instance.config in
>   application version thewhozoo-1.0.0.31 contains invalid YAML or JSON.
>   YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while parsing a block mapping in
>   "", line 7, column 5: mode: "000400" ^ expected ,
>   but found Scalar in "", line 32, column 6: -----END
>   CERTIFICATE----- ^ , JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected
>   character (p) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.

Comment: Interesting that the error message both manages to get the casing for the acronym YAML incorrect as well as that it throws a JSON exception....

Comment: You **really** should make that "UPADTE" part of your post into a separate, new, post. Update your screenshots in that post with proper indentation, otherwise that might be the first thing they notice and comment upon

Comment: Apologies. I tried to post this a new question, but StackOverflow won't let me. It limits usage to 6 questions a day. (I have a number of questions for other topics too today).

Comment: I understand, but this way the update is not going to get much attention (and I can't help you with that).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I guess I will have to post the question tomorrow. I will try figure it out in the mean time hopefully.

Comment: You can always go to edit and copy and paste the content. Then go to edit history and roll-back. Shouldn't take long once you are allowed to post again.

Comment: @Anthon, I have altered the file, which I think may solve my issue. However, I am getting a `YAML exception` again. Would you mind taking a look above please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147386/discussion-between-anthon-and-richard).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to indent your certificate data more than the column of `content`:

```
files:
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
      MI.......
      Wk.......
```

That is the way the literal scalar in block style works. As you can have empty lines in such a literal scalar, as well as (further) indented lines, the parser would otherwise not know that your scalar had ended or not (that is would not assume `/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:` to be part of the literal scalar).

Comment: Wow I just can't beleive it, it remind me my old cobol course 25 years ago, where we had to start all code lines at space 7 ! Thanks for sharing !